# How to update an object's image in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to set the image of the face down card to the image that the value of the card is. The method in KCCard, image:, returns the image of the card.

```
- (UIImage *)image:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
    if (!yesOrNo) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-blue-150-3.png"];
    } else {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-150", [self suitAsString], [self valueAsString]]];
    }
}
```

The code I am using in the deal method is as follows.

```
    int lastDealerX = 437;
    //int lastDealerY = 49;

    int lastDealerTag = 0;

    for (KCCard *aCard in dealerHand) {
        if (lastDealerTag == 0) {
            KCCardView *cardView = [[KCCardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lastDealerX, 49, 150, 215)];
            cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cardView.image = [aCard image:NO];
            cardView.tag = lastDealerTag;
            [self.view addSubview:cardView];

            lastDealerTag = lastDealerTag + 1;

            lastDealerX = lastDealerX + 42;
        } else {
            KCCardView *cardView = [[KCCardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lastDealerX, 49, 150, 215)];
            cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cardView.image = [aCard image:YES];
            cardView.tag = lastDealerTag;
            [self.view addSubview:cardView];

            lastDealerTag = lastDealerTag + 1;

            lastDealerX = lastDealerX + 42;
        }
    }
```

The KCCardView with tag 0 shows the card face down and the other card is face up. The problem is that when I want the face down card to show, it won't. Here is the show code.

```
- (IBAction)showCard:(id)sender {
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        for (KCCard *aCard in dealerHand) {
            KCCardView *cardView = (KCCardView *)view;
            if (cardView.tag == 0) {
                cardView.image = [[dealerHand objectAtIndex:0] image:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KCCard is an NSObject, KCCardView is a UIImageView, and dealerHand is an NSMutableArray.

Here is a video showing the build and run: http://aleckazarian.com/misc/Blackjack.mov
Here is the XCode project: http://aleckazarian.com/misc/Blackjack.zip

Comment: `yesOrNo` is perhaps one of the weakest variable names you can possibly have e.g. I've skimmed your code and I would still have to try and guess what it means

Comment: @Paul.s Well if it's jut me using it, then I know what it means. YES means the card shows and NO means the back shows.

Comment: This is true but give it a day/week/month/year and you'll forget what it means. It's also a bad habit to get into. Naming is something that is hard and I tend to chop and change the names of things all the time but thats so that my code will read well for the next person (most likely me) who has to work with it

Comment: I know, right after you brought it up I thought, "I'll change it after this is solved." So thanks, haha.

Comment: Even if you think it's just you who needs to understand the code, it's not. For example, you just asked everyone on Stack Overflow to read and understand your code.

Comment: I understand, but I didn't even understand the problem I had. I asked because I needed help, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking, of course. Just pointing out that it's always a good idea to use descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the connection in the nib you'll notice that it is connected to

```
showCard
```

this is a completely different method to

```
showCard:
```

In your class you implement `- (IBAction)showCard:(id)sender;` therefore you need to break the connection in Interface builder and reconnect it.

---

## Update

The second time I ran your program I got

```
-[UIRoundedRectButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68612e0
```

This looks like it's because you are iterating over the `view`'s subviews and checking if `0 == tag`. 0 is the default value for tag so essentially mostly every view will respond true unless you have explicitly set the tags to something else. The problem code it

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    for (KCCard *aCard in dealerHand) {
        KCCardView *cardView = (KCCardView *)view;
        if (cardView.tag == 0) {          // <------- This is the bad check
            cardView.image = [((KCCard *)[dealerHand objectAtIndex:0]) image:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

To fix this either do one of these (they are in order of my preference - I wouldn't go near 3 or 4 in this case):

1. Keep a reference to the `cardView`'s in an array
2. Give the `cardView`'s a non zero `tag` when they are created
3. Use `respondsToSelector:`
4. Test for the class `[cardView isKindOf:[UIButton class]];

Comment: Fixed it, then this happened when I hit the button. -[UIRoundedRectButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8204130

Comment: Same problem. cardView.image = [((KCCard *)[dealerHand objectAtIndex:0]) image:YES]; -[UIRoundedRectButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b0da70

Comment: OMG!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR TELLING ME ABOUT THE DEFAULT ZERO TAG!!! I changed the dealer tag int to 44 and cardView.tag == 44 and it worked after!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: The docs are really good once you get used to reading them [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25)

Comment: I read them how long ago and just didn't even think of tags. I never use them. Thanks a bunch Paul!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know, what kind of object `[dealerHand objectAtIndex:0]` is, thus it cannot respond to `image:`. Try this:

```
cardView.image = [((KCCard *)[dealerHand objectAtIndex:0]) image:YES];
```

Comment: Nope.

-[PlayMoney showCard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e0de70

Comment: I uploaded my XCode project if you'd like to take a look at the whole thing.

Comment: Just took a look at your XCode project. Seems like the outlet for the button action is not linked properly.

Comment: I fixed it like @Paul.s told me, and it gave: -[UIRoundedRectButton setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8204130